# Is there an equivalent of django-hitcount template tags but for views?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am using [django-hitcount](https://django-hitcount.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#counting-hits) and am stumped on counting hits within the `views.py` for my app. The documentation suggests using this

```
from hitcount.models import HitCount
from hitcount.views import HitCountMixin

# first get the related HitCount object for your model object
hit_count = HitCount.objects.get_for_object(your_model_object)

# next, you can attempt to count a hit and get the response
# you need to pass it the request object as well
hit_count_response = HitCountMixin.hit_count(request, hit_count)

# your response could look like this:
# UpdateHitCountResponse(hit_counted=True, hit_message='Hit counted: session key')
# UpdateHitCountResponse(hit_counted=False, hit_message='Not counted: session key has active hit')
```

However, I am not looking for responses to a HitCount object. I only want to count the hits in a similar manner to how the template tags provide, like this

```
{% get_hit_count for [object] within ["days=1,minutes=30"] %}
```

How exactly do I get the hit count for an object in a given timeframe inside of the `views.py` ?

Comment: did you solve this? I am trying to do the same!

Comment: No, unfortunately. I haven't found a reliable alternative either, so I just shelved this feature in my project for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same predicament. So I looked into their views and implemented what you are asking in a function-based view. Let's pretend we want to count all views on a user's profile. The view:

```py
import hitcount # import entire package
from hitcount.models import HitCount 

def profile(request):
    my_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    # mark it
    hit_count = HitCount.objects.get_for_object(my_profile)
    hit_count_response = hitcount.views.HitCountMixin.hit_count(request, hit_count)

    # count the views
    profile_views = my_profile.hit_count.hits

    return render( request, 'profile.html', locals() )
```

I found that I had to import entire hitcount package to work with `hitcount.views.HitCountMixin`. I guess my app was confusing  `hitcount.views.HitCountMixin` with `hitcount.models.HitCountMixin` probably because I had imported everything from my `models.py`. So, if in your views.py you have `from .models import *` like me, it is wise to import entire package to specify which HitCountMixin you are referring to... Just like in the code above...

Anyway,  ensure that the model you want to count hits inherits from `hitcount.models.HitCountMixin` and that you have a generic relationship to `hitcount.models.HitCount)` e.g.

```py
from hitcount.models import HitCountMixin, HitCount 

class Profile(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hit_count_generic = GenericRelation( HitCount, object_id_field='object_pk',
                                         related_query_name='hit_count_generic_relation' )
```

That's it. Logout and login again to your app - I guess to refresh the Django sessions framework (I had to).Then, at the template, call the profile views like a regular local ...

```
<p> Profile Views: {{profile_views}} </p>
```